# Null object Access debug in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

confused about the debug message，
The object at dereference depth 2 is being used before it was allocated

`extip_axi4_uvc.wr_master.driver.m_write_addr_delay_shaper.set_periodic_profile(150);`

what does dereference depth 2 mean? is that means the driver object is not instantiated in the wr_master agent?

Comment: which compiler gave you that message? Try a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ether set a breakpoint and examine each member in the path for *nullness*, or add checks

```
if (extip_axi4_uvc == null) $error("extip_axi4_uvc is null);
else if (extip_axi4_uvc.wr_master == null) $error("extip_axi4_uvc.wr_master is null);
else if ...
```